# How to assing a given value randomly in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have 30 peoples waiting for result out of 10. I want to assign each of 30 peoples: 7, 8 or 10 result randomly.

Peoples in excel are:

```
A1:A30
```

Random numbers in Excel

```
B1, C1, D1  //Which means B1=8, C1=7 and D1=10
```

The random number to keep on:

```
E1 to E30
```

Comment: Rephrase your question please. Do you want to give each out of 30 people one out of three numbers (7,8 or 10) randomly?

Comment: Each of the 30 people has to be randomly assigned to group 7 or group 8 or group 10? And after that each group must have 10 members?

Comment: Yes you are, I want to give each of 30 people one of three numbers (7, 8 or 10 randomly)

Comment: Axel, now I edited my question as clear as possible.

Comment: Do we have to produce a reference to B1,C1,D1? Which cell in each row do you want to hold the result number?

Comment: I want to hold the result on E1 to E30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a random integer in a range, use the `randbetween(start,end)` function. This will produce a random integer between the start and end parameters inclusively. Since your numbers are not contiguous, you can simply index them and perform a lookup using `vlookup(randbetween(startindex,endindex),...)` to get a random value from the table.

Check out this [Example Excel File](http://www.filedropper.com/book1_4) I created.

Use the following steps to get your desired result:

1. List the people in column A
2. Create a lookup table in Columns G and H
   containing your desired result values.
3. In your result column (column E in the example below), add the formula: `=vlookup(randbetween(1,3),G:H,2,false)`

Column E will now contain either the numbers 7,8,or 10 for each person.

If you want to generalize this and allow any number of different values in your result lookup table, you can change the formula in column E to: `=vlookup(randbetween(1,counta(G:G)-1),G:H,2,false)`.
*Note: The `-1` is only needed if your lookup table has a header row.*
This will select a random value from all non-empty rows in your result lookup table.

In the example below, I added a header row to row 1, and the people start in row 2, for clarity.

```
+---+---------+---+---+---+--------+---+-----------+--------------+
|   |    A    | B | C | D |    E   | F |     G     |       H      |
+---+---------+---+---+---+--------+---+-----------+--------------+
| 1 |  Names  |   |   |   | RESULT |   | Result ID | RESULT Value |
+---+---------+---+---+---+--------+---+-----------+--------------+
| 2 | Person1 |   |   |   |    7   |   |     1     |       7      |
+---+---------+---+---+---+--------+---+-----------+--------------+
| 3 | Person2 |   |   |   |    7   |   |     2     |       8      |
+---+---------+---+---+---+--------+---+-----------+--------------+
| 4 | Person3 |   |   |   |   10   |   |     3     |      10      |
+---+---------+---+---+---+--------+---+-----------+--------------+
| 5 | Person4 |   |   |   |    8   |   |           |              |
+---+---------+---+---+---+--------+---+-----------+--------------+
```